# Android Studio Error : Could not find Android Buld Tools

Tags: java, android, dependencies, mobile-development

So, My Friend who is in University wanted me to check out his Application,
He sent me the Project File and When I tried to Run it I was greeted with an Error Message that Detailed.

```
Could not Find com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.3.2-5309881.
```

Any Help would be Highly Appreciated (:

Required by:
    project: app

[image]

Comment: Did you try syncing your project? So that it downloads the dependencies automatically?

Comment: Did you try File - Invalidate cacae / restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AAPT2 moved to Google's Maven repository, to use AAPT2, make sure that you have a `google()` dependency in your `build.gradle` file, as shown here:

```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          google() // here
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
      }
  } 

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          google() // and here
          jcenter()
  }
```

See: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/#aapt2_gmaven